# How to get the full entity object with a query Room using a table with FK

Tags: java, android, sql, kotlin, android-room

Let's say I have these tables :

### Table - User

> Stores the users

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "USER"
)
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_name")
    val name: String
)
```

### Table - Item

> Store the items it's like a product

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "ITEM"
)
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_description")
    val description: String
)
```

### Table - Special

> Store an speciality for product 1 Special needs a Product to exist

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "SPECIAL",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Item::class,
        parentColumns = ["item_id"],
        childColumns = ["special_item_id"]
    )]
)
data class Special(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "special_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "special_item_id")
    val coupon_product_id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "special_name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "special_description")
    val description: String

)
```

### Table -- Favourite

> Stores the favourite Specials from an user

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "TB_FAVOURITE",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = User::class,
        parentColumns = ["user_id"],
        childColumns = ["favourite_user_id"]
    ), ForeignKey(
        entity = Special::class,
        parentColumns = ["special_id"],
        childColumns = ["favourite_special_id"]
    )]
)
data class Favourite(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite_user_id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite_special_id")
    val specialId: Int

)
```

My question is, how can I make a query to select all the Specials and then creating like a class that stores if it's favourite of the user or not. It's one user app for the moment, it's for a demo app. So, user will always be the same so I can hardcode the `findById` and send the id of the user.

### The goal

Is to get a result of a query as List that contains :

1. All of the Specials
2. In the SomeClass should contain the Item of the Special inside
3. A flag to know if it's favourite for that driver or not

The thing is I want to be able to map the result of the room database to my desired object, so I guess the query is more important than the mapper, I know how to do the mapper.

Note that I'm using an `assets/database/mydb.db` file to start the database I don't know if it matters.

How would be the query to do that? Is there any improvement of the structure of the db to make it easier?

Comment: have a look at [Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Embedded). When you use it you define the joins with [Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Relation)

Comment: @Stachu could you add an example as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

you could create class like this:

```kotlin
class SpecialWithFavourite {
    @Embedded
    var special: Special? = null
    @Relation(parentColumn = "special_item_id", entityColumn = "item_id")
    var item: Item? = null
    @Relation(parentColumn = "special_id", entityColumn = "favourite_special_id")
    var favourite: Favourite? = null
}
```

and then extract it using dao query like this:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface DaoSpecialWithFavourite {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT SPECIAL.* FROM SPECIAL INNER JOIN TB_FAVOURITE WHERE TB_FAVOURITE.favourite_user_id = :userId")
    fun getLD(userId: Long): List<SpecialWithFavourite>
}
```

another option is using a [View](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/creating-views), especially if you only need fiew fields

```
@DatabaseView("SELECT SPECIAL.*, ITEM.item_name FROM SPECIAL INNER JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.item_id = SPECIAL.special_item_id")
class FavSpecial {
    var name: String? = null
    @Embedded
    var special: Special? = null
}
```

as per discussion in the comments, new `Favourite`

```
data class Favourite(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite_user_id")
    val userid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite_special_id")
    val specialId: Int
)
```

this way you still keep the constraints, and the user can have multiple favourite specials

Comment: I'm having problems when trying to insert, Failure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: TB_FAVOURITE.favourite_user_id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY))

Comment: Did I create the FAVOURITE table wrong? with that primary key?

Comment: for `FAVOURITE` primary key is `favourite_user_id` which is constrained by `USER.user_id`, so you can only have one per user. Is it as inteded? I would create a separate key for that table, especially that that will allow user to have multiple favourites

Comment: No, I want to be a table where I can find for instance the user 1 have as a favourite 2, 3, 4 so first column is user_id that can be any user_id of the database and the favourite needs to be the special_id.

Comment: But I need to add a PK there... so I don't know if both have to be the PK or what. but could be that there's more than one different user-id.

Comment: I get that but right now you can only have single row in `FAVOURITE` per user, beacause that field is primary key - see my propoosed new `Favourite` entity

Comment: But I don't get how it's possible since on my SQLite browser I can create many rows

Comment: Then I have to remove the FK?

Comment: no, you keep the ForeignKey definition as it was, it's just that this table will have a PK different than `user_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220132/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-stachu).